# What is the best template for a WCF Oracle app?

Tags: c#, wcf, oracle, templates, rest

I need to create a proof-of-concept app for querying our Oracle database via http/a browser (specifically, IE8 and IE9).

What is the best starting point for this - the "WCF REST Service Application" template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this: How to Create WCF Service to Retrieve Data From the Oracle Database:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-create-wcf-service-to-retrieve-data-from-the-oracle-database/